# Google analytics does not present non-string custom event parameters (Custom definitions)

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm developing a Flutter application and I'm sending event analytics using [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) package. I'm sending custom params with my analytics as the following:

My code:

```
final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

void onGroupCreate(String groupId, double totalInvites, bool isStatus) {
      analytics.logEvent(
        name: "create_group",
        parameters: <String, dynamic>{
          'user_id': globals.user.userId,
          'group_id': groupId,
          'total_invites': totalInvites,
          'is_status': isStatus
        },
      );
    }
```

I have added GA `Custom definitions`, based on my params. But I can only see `String` analytics (`double` and `bool` params aren't shown).

**Does GA4 accept only String values?** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the custom dimensions [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#overview), dimension's value type is `Text` while custom metrics are `Integers`.

**Boolean** parameters should be converted to Strings.

**Integer** parameters should be created over `metrics` and not `dimensions`.

Comment: Thank you so much for it! I was already desperate to make it working, but now will try tracking numeric value with Custom Metric. Will let you know after couple days of data aggregation whether it will work. I wish I've seen this in documentation. Thank you!